# intrinsic-ness of ordinary derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry

The Laplace operator (or only the Laplace-Beltrami form of it?) is intrinsic: 
defined only in terms of the metric; does not reference the ambient space.

The Laplace operator is a multidimensional form of the second derivative.

Then, can anything be said about the first and second derivative as to their intrinsic-ness? Is it as simple as saying that the first derivative slope is effectively an angle with respect to the ambient space, whereas the curvature is preserved regardless of how a curve is translated/rotated in the ambient plane?  Thus curvature intrinsic, 1st derivative not? And what for the second derivative, which is only an approximate curvature.

In several differential geometry books I see a statement of a 'fundamental theorem of curves',
that the principal curvature uniquely defines a curve up to a rigid rotation. 
Montiel and Ros *Curves and Surfaces* follows this by saying,

> the curvature is a genuine intrinsic coordinate of plane curves.

suggesting that this is related to what makes the curvature intrinsic. However, the first derivative also uniquely defines a curve, up to a constant.

Comment: There are lots of different directions in which the idea of taking derivatives generalizes in higher dimensions. For example, exterior derivatives are always intrinsic. If you want to take higher derivatives of a function $M \to \mathbb{R}$, e.g. to write down some sort of Taylor series approximation, then the appropriate formalism is the notion of jet bundles, which are also intrinsic.